# UIImage, check if contain image

Tags: ios, uiimage

If I instantiate a UIImage like this :

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

The object is created but it doesn't contain any image.

How I can check if my object contains an image or not?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can check if it has any image data.

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

CGImageRef cgref = [image CGImage];
CIImage *cim = [image CIImage];

if (cim == nil && cgref == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"no underlying data");
}
[image release];
```

## Swift Version

```
let image = UIImage()

let cgref = image.cgImage
let cim = image.ciImage

if cim == nil && cgref == nil {
    print("no underlying data")
}
```

Comment: But [image CIImage]; availables only in iOS 5. What about 4.3 ?

Answer (score 16):

Check for `cgImage` or `ciImage`, in Swift 3

```
public extension UIImage {

  public var hasContent: Bool {
    return cgImage != nil || ciImage != nil
  }
}
```

> CGImage: If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object,
>   the value of the property is NULL.
>
> CIImage: If the UIImage object was initialized using a CGImageRef, the
>   value of the property is nil.

Comment: Crashes if there is no image... Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional

Answer (score 0):

Check with CGImageRef with itself wheather it contains null value means UIImage object not contains image.......

Answer (score 0):

This is updated version of @Kreiri, I put in a method and fixed logic error:

```
- (BOOL)containsImage:(UIImage*)image {
    BOOL result = NO;

    CGImageRef cgref = [image CGImage];
    CIImage *cim = [image CIImage];

    if (cim != nil || cgref != NULL) { // contains image
        result = YES;
    }

    return result;
}
```

An UIImage could only based on CGImageRef or CIImage. If both is nil means there is no image. Example use of giving method:

```
if (![self containsImage:imageview.image]) {
    [self setImageWithYourMethod];
}
```

hope it will help someone.